# FIGMA: How can I make a prototype link from one page to another page's specific element?

Tags: prototype, figma

I would like to create a prototype link from one page to another page's specific element.

So the prototype link shouldn't be towards the whole page, but to the specific element of that page (i.e. towards the contact form at the bottom of the page).

You can see the desired result on the photo. Is this possible to do in Figma and how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Figma natively.

**To save you time:** I already tried the steps on [this article](https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/can-you-prototype-across-pages-figma/), but it didn't work when I tested the prototype. But you can try it if you want, maybe you can get it to work.

For now, you have to get along with Figma's constraint where all screens involved in your prototype / demo, should all be present on the same page.